# What is this HTTP error [plugin: Google Calendar Events]?

Tags: calendar

I am getting this error on my Google Calendar Events plugin:

> Feed 1: There are no HTTP transports available which can complete the requested request. Please ensure your feed URL is correct.

I have tested this plugin on a web hosting company and it works fine. But when I moved my WordPress site to a local hosting machine I get this error. My server runs on IIS6 and Windows Server 2003. What could this error be? Does it have to do with Google web extensions not being installed?

Comment: Does installing google web extensions help?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your server does not have access to [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). With most hosts, you can enable this with php.ini.

Comment: If this helped out, please vote up or mark as "answered." Thanks!